# Why did they allow different brooms to be used in Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did they allow different brooms to be used in Quidditch? In Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, it seems like the Nimbus 2000 would give Harry an unfair advantage over people who have regular brooms. And in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, the Slytherins with their new Nimbus 2001s would have an unfair advantage over the Gryffindors (they did; they scored a lot more points than Gryffindor). What's the logic behind allowing different brooms to be used in a competitive sport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many sports allow personal variations on equipment, sneakers, bikes, clubs, bats, car racing, etc. Quidditch is no different. There is no unfair advantage as anyone could use the same broom. Additionally, Harry is in a varsity/school/kid team which often have more relaxed rules compared to professional level/adult leagues.

To wit, Harry's broom does not seem to give him a significant advantage compared to other seekers, as they are always keeping pace with him. He's shown to be exceptionally good at flying with any broom, the Nimbus just keeping up with his abilities.

Comment: They do still set limits, though... with bats, specifically, only kids can use aluminum... the higher the level of play you get, they become more limiting and require only wood bats. It's not unheard-of to restrict these things... Golf does the same thing with golf balls.

Comment: @Catija even in MLB, sure you're limited to solid core wooden bats, but can be any number of wood types, length, weight combinations. But you did catch me before my edit regarding the same point re levels of play :)

Comment: Sure, I think the issue here is that while they certainly **could** use the same equipment, due to cost, it's not feasible. I don't know if there's a direct RW equivalent other than perhaps horses in polo/jumping... more expensive horses are likely to perform better, regardless of the skill of the rider. The closest other thing I could think of was the introduction of the [clap skate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clap_skate) for speed skating.

Comment: @Catija what about bicycle competitions that allow you to bring your own bike as long as it fits certain restrictions? Or car racing where anything goes (compared to stock car racing). As to the cost vs feasibility, look at modern professional sports teams, where some teams have much higher quality equipment due to attracting better sponsors.